# WooCommerce show orders per user role on page with shortcode

Tags: woocommerce, frontend, shortcode, orders, user-roles

I would like to show a list of orders, of a specific user role, on a page at the frontend.
It could be the same list of order as is being shown in the `orders` tab on the `my account` page but with all the orders that equals a specific user role.

If possible I would like to use it as a `shortcode`.

I have been looking on  [this page](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/wiki/wc_get_orders-and-WC_Order_Query#general)  to get orders, but I couldn't find out how to implement the role of the user.
Neither am I sure of the creation of the `shortcode`.

```
add_shortcode('your-shortcode', 'yourFunction');
      function yourFunction(){
        $args = array(
            'customer_id' => 12,
        );
        $orders = wc_get_orders( $args );  
}
```

Comment: This can be problematic. The reason why I say this is because there is a rights system behind each order that prevents other users to see an order from another customer. Do you want to print the content of the order too or just the list like in the MyAccount -> Orders page without any functionality?

Comment: We are working with a system of sales agents, we divided our customers in roles to organise them by sales agent. So Role#1=SalesAgent#1 Role#2=SalesAgent#2 etc.
The sales agent has higher functionalities than the other roles and we would like the sales agents to be able to see the orders placed by its customers.
The list how it is on the MyAccount -> Orders page would be good.
Even only 3 columns with: "Ordernumber, Orderstatus, Customer" would work.

Comment: But if the agents should see a list of your customers, the MyAccount page is the absolute wrong place for this. There is a rights system in the WordPress backend so you can give the agents the role to view the dashboard and to only view the WooCommerce orders. Why don't you do this? (You can use a user role editor for this).

Comment: Because then they would see all the orders. This is not what we want.
Agent1 should see only the orders of his clients. 
And I don't want to show it on the MyAccount page, it was only an example of how it could look like.

Comment: This need to be done by author instead of user roles (or if it's not possible by author, you should add a custom field for each product where you will add the ID of the related Agent)… Then you will be able to query the orders that belongs to an agent.

Comment: Would it be possible to list orders based on a custom field in the order instead?